# Dgrid - how do I merge cells in a single row

Tags: javascript, merge, dojo, dgrid

Few of the rows in my d-grid in a subsection and the row object has an attribute to identify such a row.

Can I merge this row cells into one and change the CSS of the particular row to reflect the subsection part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the 'subRows' function of dgrid.

How to implement this is well explained [here](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/defining_grid_structures/).
A demo of how it works is [here](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/defining_grid_structures/demo/subRows.html)